# How can I get Euclidean distance matrix from adjacency matrix if the distance between neighbours is fixed to one

Tags: matlab, euclidean-distance, adjacency-matrix

I have adjacency matrix,I don't know the location of the points only I know the adjacency matrix and distance between neighbors are equal.

so how I get the distance between points??:

is there any algorithm do that

Answer (score 1):

> so how I get the distance between points??

In general, you can't, assuming you're using Euclidean distance as tagged. With the information you have given, you can't come up with a unique layout (embedding) of the graph.

As a small counter-example, take the adjacency matrix:

```
[0 1 1]
[1 0 0]
[1 0 0]
```

Vertex 1 is connected to Vertex 2 and Vertex 3 forming an angle. The angle between segments (1,2) and (1,3) can be anything we want from 0 ° to 180° making the distance between Vertices 2 and 3 between 0 and 2 units.

To come up with anything reasonable you'll have to impose some sort of layout on the graph first.

Answer (score 0):

Since the adjacency matrix represents a graph, you need to traverse the graph to find the possible paths. You can do that using [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), since the graph is not weighted. keep in mind that the distance between some points might be infinite, since there might not be a path from one to another